# I can't set value for state from props

Tags: reactjs

Why this code isn't work?
I just want to set state for this class from props but the state alway empty.

```html
class BillsList extends React.Component{ 
    constructor (props: any){
            super(props);
            this.state = {currentList : this.props.list};
    };
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.list); //It worked..!
        console.log(this.state.currentList); //But this is empty
        return(
            <div className="bill_list">
                {this.state.currentList.map((item,i)=>
                    <BillsItem key ={i} value={item} />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

'list' is array object like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV5VK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code as below:

```
class BillsList extends React.Component{ 
    constructor (props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {currentList : props.list};
    };
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.list); //It worked..!
        console.log(this.state.currentList); //But this is empty
        return(
            <div className="bill_list">
                {this.state.currentList.map((item,i)=>
                    <BillsItem key ={i} value={item} />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: It worked for me. Anyway you can read this for more info: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Answer (score 0):

I think your props is received after the component is initialized. So in that case one need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state.
In your case it would like below

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.list !== nextProps.list) {
    this.setState({
      currentList: nextProps.list,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! It worked
But why does it work with  String that do not work with array object?

Comment: It does not depend on the state. It depends on how the props is sent to the component. If your data is fetched from other source(like http) then it would take some time for it to be received and then sent to the component.